# PublicKey extraction via Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to automate my process of extracting SNK-PublicKeys with a Batch that I call via the External Tools-feature of Visual Studio.

This would work perfectly fine if I just could get it running. Seriously, I guess I'm the only one who thinks that Batch / CMD-programming is more difficult than C++.

That's my code so far, I used most of another MSDN tutorial. But all I get is that output in VS Console:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET sn ="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\sn.exe"
%sn% -p "%1" "%1.PublicKey"
%sn% -tp "%1.PublicKey"
```

My output [input: "D:\Sicherung\Visual Studio\Workspace\TestApp\src\TestApp\TestApp.snk" - without "" of course]

Result:

> '-p' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   '-tp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a space between `sn` and `=` which is making the variable technically `%sn %`. Remove the space.

```
SET sn="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\sn.exe"
```

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the problem. But I still have troubles because of the spaces in the path passed through the arguments. Tho' I set "" around the %1, it says that it can't find the path "D:\Sicherung\Visual" ...

Comment: It's because `%1` contains quotes by itself, so you've essentially got `"" D:\Sicherung\Visual Studio\etc\""` and the quotes are getting escaped. Use `%~1` instead so that the quotes in `%1` get removed first.

Comment: Doesn't change anything, it still doesn't get it. I've never seen path-arguments that worked the first time. One of the things I don't understand, sometimes it works, sometimes not.

Comment: @SharpShade - I just realized that you're calling the script like `script.bat D:\Sicherung\Visual Studio\ ` and not `script.bat "D:\Sicherung\Visual Studio\"`, which is totally going to break everything. Always put the path in quotes; right now %1 is being stored as "D:\Sicherung\Visual" and the rest of the path is being stored in %2.

Comment: Yep, you're right. That was the problem. Now I get my output. Thank you!